# Chart.js: Get point index from chart.getPointsAtEvent(e)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, charts, chart.js

I am looking to make my chart (made with Chart.js) a little more interactive and I would like to get a point's index (of its dataset) with the following code:

```
canvas.onclick = function(e) {
  const points = chart.getPointsAtEvent(e);
  // something like `point.getIndex()` would be great so that I know where this point is in the original dataset
};
```

Anybody have a good solution for this?

Comment: I am currently solving this by looking up the index of the label but it is a bit hacky...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do an indexOf (instead of a label lookup) because it refers to the exact same object in the points collection

```
canvas.onclick = function (evt) {
    var points = chart.getPointsAtEvent(evt);
    alert(chart.datasets[0].points.indexOf(points[0]));
};
```

Also, for a multi series line chart `getPointsAtEvent(evt)` returns points from all datasets. So the same code would work irrespective of how many datasets you have or which of the datasets you click on.

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/yxz2sjam/

Comment: Thanks but I don't think this is a simpler solution because when there are multiple datasets, you'd need to first find the correct one.

Comment: Agree, but checking labels will cause problems if you have duplicate labels (eg. Sat, Sun, Mon.... Fri, Sat, Sun, Mon...). Plus you might want to check what happens with addData - I believe the dataset label was not being written for the new points, so any match you do based on datasetLabel will also have problems.

Comment: That said, definitely go for the solution that seems simpler knowing the data you have.

Comment: @Macks - just did a quick test and realized something. For a line chart it both points from all datasets make it to the points collection. So the above code should work irrespective of how many datasets you have or which of the datasets you click on.